# Updating ProgressBar with a label periodically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working on an app where I need to use the QProgressBar to keep the user informed of the progress. But, instead of updating the progressbar in steps I would like to use setMaximum(0) to show a 'busy' indicator on the progressbar and update a QLabel to show the current stage. I do this to keep everything simple.

Here's a mock UI to simplify the explanation.

[image]

This is the corresponding code:

```
class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    relpath = 'ui/test.ui'
    uifile = join(dirname(sys.argv[0]), relpath)
    uic.loadUi(uifile, self)
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_updating)

  def start_updating(self):
    self.progressBar.setMaximum(0)
    self.label.setText("Func 1")
    sleep(3) # in real app do something here
    self.label.setText("Func 2")
    sleep(3) # in real app do something else here
    self.label.setText("Func 3")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = TestWindow()
  window.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I run this, then only the last state of the QLabel is shown ("Func 3") and the 'busy' mode is not shown on the progressbar until the last update to the label text. Can anyone help me understand why this doesn't work and if there's a better way to update the label periodically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not execute heavy tasks in the GUI thread since they block the eventloop preventing the GUI from being updated, for example in your case the label is not updated. Instead you must execute that task in another thread and send the information that updates the GUI through signals:

```py
import os
import sys
import time

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def run_task(self):
        self.started.emit()
        self.textChanged.emit("Func 1")
        time.sleep(3)  # in real app do something here
        self.textChanged.emit("Func 2")
        time.sleep(3)  # in real app do something else here
        self.textChanged.emit("Func 3")
        self.finished.emit()


class TestWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        relpath = "ui/test.ui"
        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        uifile = os.path.join(current_dir, relpath)
        uic.loadUi(uifile, self)

        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        thread.start()

        self.m_worker = Worker()
        self.m_worker.moveToThread(thread)
        self.m_worker.started.connect(self.onStarted)
        self.m_worker.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
        self.m_worker.textChanged.connect(self.update_label)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.m_worker.run_task)
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onStarted(self):
        self.progressBar.setMaximum(0)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onFinished(self):
        self.progressBar.setMaximum(1)
        self.progressBar.setValue(1)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def update_label(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TestWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc. That was explained very well and it works for me. I plan to use the same progress bar to show the status of different tasks that are executed from the GUI, so should I create separate worker threads for each? What's the best practice here?